# Can you get held at immigration for not paying hotel bills in Philippines?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, philippines

A friend of mine booked a cheap lodge in Philippines through booking.com. But the day before his flight, he found a nicer hotel to stay and even found some last minute bad reviews of this cheap property and its owner. So he decided not to stay at this lodge but forgot to inform them that he will no longer stay. A few days later the lodge contacted him by text message, threatening him that they will file a case at immigration regarding this unpaid hotel bill, probably for a no show fee. My friend ignored the text but the lodge seems to be aggressive and they keep on texting him every month, not to remind, but to threaten him that they will file a case at the immigration.

Our concern is that every text message that the lodge will send my friend, they will give him a different case number with immigration, so we are not sure if this text is true or just plain scam. The last text he got was few days ago and claims that they have already filed the case and that my friend will be held at the immigration and can never leave Philippines until he settles this bill.

Comment: How much money did they demand, and is it actually owed, given his contract with the hotel?

Comment: 2,300php that's around 50usd roughly. and one more thing, we got a confirmation email from booking.com saying "No-show fees waived, by property".

Comment: That makes it sound more like a scam. How do they want the money paid?

Comment: the amount that i mentioned above is the price of the room based on the email from booking.com. but their text messages are saying that they wanted him to contact them through phone or email so they can inform him how much he needs settle or to pay. so i guess this really is just a scam. my friend just don't want to waste time going to that cheap hotel to confirm with the owner if the texts were true because the online reviews of their property really shows how rude the owner is.

Comment: I'm not surprised the owner is being rude -- your friend was very inconsiderate, and may have cost the owner some money in turned-away custom.

Comment: The additional data again makes a difference. Given zero notice, I would expect there to be a legitimate no-show charge, and I'm surprised at the booking.com message. Depending on the contract, it may be just one night, or it may be more. The only way to know what is actually owed is to check the booking terms. Regardless of whether there is an actual immigration hold, your friend probably owes some money, so I don't understand the failure to call the hotel to arrange to settle it.

Comment: _"they keep on texting him every month, not to remind, but to threaten him that they will file a case at the immigration"_ - If they were able to do that, surely they would already have done so?

Comment: Your friend should check on booking.com, and in the confirmation email. There are rules about no-show and cancellation, and you friend should apply such rules, so he should pay. Note: the more he delay the payment, the more the hotel could charge (because of missing payment). You said there were a lot of negative comments about the hotel, so you can expect non-professional behaviour on their side, but this is not an excuse not to pay your debts.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that he will be detained at immigration for a small amount like 50$. If he didn't give the hotel any identifying documents, such as a passport, it is unlikely they can even do anything about it because they can't prove it is him just by name.